# How to bind ListView to a collection and refresh it real time

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am binding my ListView to my Realm database, but it doesn't refresh it when I add a new item into it. I am adding new items using another page.

I am using here as reference: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/mvvm#binding-itemssource

My Model:

```
public class Category : RealmObject
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string CategoryID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }

        public string CategoryDetails { get; set; }

        [Backlink(nameof(Note.CategoryOfNote))]
        public IQueryable<Note> Notes { get; }

        public string CategoryIcon { get; set; }
        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    }
```

My XAML file containing ListView

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="NEWCAT" 
                     Clicked="NewCat_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <ListView x:Name="categoryList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                  ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped"
                  HasUnevenRows="True">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     Padding="10"
                                     Spacing="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Path=CategoryTitle}" 
                                   FontSize="Medium"/>
                            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsExpanded}" 
                                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Button Text="Notes"
                                        Clicked="NotesButton_Clicked" />
                                <Button Text="Edit" 
                                        Clicked="EditButton_Clicked"/>
                                <Button Text="Delete"
                                        Clicked="DeleteButton_Clicked"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

And my ViewModel
(DBServices.GetCategories is a static method that returns a collection of categories from Realm DB. And BaseViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        private Category _oldCategory;
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            RefreshCategories();
        }

        private void RefreshCategories()
        {
            Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(DBServices.GetCategories());
        }


        private ObservableCollection<Category> _Categories;
        public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                return _Categories;
            }
            set
            {
                _Categories = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Categories");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is OnPropertyChanged method in BaseViewModel class

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

When I click to the toolbar button, it pushes a new form page to create a new category. Then it just adds that category to the Realm DB. Afterwards it pops itself. But I see no change in my ListView.

EDIT: I can see new items in ListView when I restarted the app. But I want it to be listed as I add them.

Comment: So you are adding objects to the DB in another page, and then pop and expect the MainPage to have the listview updated?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro yes. It updates the list only after the application is restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Xamarin Forms [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to tell the ListView it needs to update.

On the page where the new category is added to the Realm DB, at some point after the category is added but before the page is popped, you would send a message to tell the ListView page to update. This may look something like:

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Update listview");
```

In your MainViewModel you'll need to subscribe to the message and then act upon it. This could be something like:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddCategoryPage>(this, "Update listview", (sender) =>
{
    RefreshCategories();
});
```

Two items to note when using the MessagingCenter.

1. The message passed must be identical between the sender and subscriber. In this case the message is "Update listview". Because it must be identical, you would probably want to define the message in separate class so it can be referenced by both the sender and subscriber.
2. When subscribing to a message you have to make sure that you unsubscribe. A popular pattern is to subscribe when the page appears and unsubscribe when the page disappears. A different pattern may work better for you though.

On a side note, you shouldn't need the full property definition for `Categories`. The `ObservableCollection` will handle the notification when items are added or removed. Just set `Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();` once and then only add or remove items. You don't need to new it up on every DB call.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried it, but the ListView didn't change.

Comment: Wait, it works! Thank you again. But I'm still confused, why did we need to send a message to make it refresh? 'Binding' should be doing it automatically, shouldn't it?

Comment: @FarukD The ListView is "bound" to the Categories property, but what is updating the Categories property? You only update the Categories property place in one place, the RefreshCategories method, and you only call the RefreshCategories method in the constructor of the page. Therefore, Categories is only ever updated when the page is constructed. You have to tell the list to check for updated data.

Answer (score 0):

To test the XAML and ViewModel only, try replacing `DBServices.GetCategories()` with the following in the ViewModel:

```
public static IEnumerable<Category> TestCategories
{
    get
    {
        yield return new Category { CategoryTitle = "title 1" };
        yield return new Category { CategoryTitle = "title 2" };
    }
}
...
public MainViewModel()
{
    Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(TestCategories);
}
```

`DBServices.GetCategories()` should also be tested for expected output, not shown here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see title 1 and title 2 in my ListView with this code. I know DBServices.GetCategories() returns expected output because when I restarted the app, I can see the new categories I added.